# PDFKit get error -[PDFView setAutoScales:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdfkit

I have code like this tutorial but I got an eror

```
#import <PDFKit/PDFKit.h>
PDFView *View = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
View.autoScales = NO ;
View.displayDirection = kPDFDisplayDirectionHorizontal;
View.displayMode = kPDFDisplaySinglePageContinuous;
View.displaysRTL = YES ;
[View setDisplaysPageBreaks:YES];
[View setDisplayBox:kPDFDisplayBoxTrimBox];
[View zoomIn:self];
[self.view addSubview:View];

NSURL * URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"test" withExtension: @ "pdf" ];
PDFDocument * document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: URL];
View.document = document;
```

But after build I got this eror

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFView setAutoScales:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103519410'
```

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: I had same problem. Check the post below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194001/how-to-load-pdf-using-pdfkit-for-ipad