# How to load pdf using PDFKit for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this piece of code.

```
LoadPdf(void* currentView,NSData* content,NSString* urlName) {
    UIView tmpView = (UIView)currentView;

    NSData *data = content;

    PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];

    PDFView *pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
    pdfView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    pdfView.autoScales = NO ;
    pdfView.displayDirection = kPDFDisplayDirectionHorizontal;
    pdfView.displayMode = kPDFDisplaySinglePageContinuous;
    pdfView.displaysRTL = YES ;
    [pdfView setDisplaysPageBreaks:YES];
    [pdfView setDisplayBox:kPDFDisplayBoxTrimBox];
    pdfView.document = pdfDocument;

    [tmpView addSubview:pdfView];
}
```

But it is not loading the PDF in the view. Also if I CGRectMake the entire PDF is not displayed in the debugger. How can I initialize PDFView and load it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High Aan,

tested it on myself with the following Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *tmpView = [self view];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"local File on disk.pdf"];

    PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];

    PDFView *pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
    pdfView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    pdfView.autoScales = NO ;
    pdfView.displayDirection = kPDFDisplayDirectionHorizontal;
    pdfView.displayMode = kPDFDisplaySinglePageContinuous;
    pdfView.displaysRTL = YES ;
    [pdfView setDisplaysPageBreaks:YES];
    [pdfView setDisplayBox:kPDFDisplayBoxTrimBox];
    pdfView.document = pdfDocument;

    [tmpView addSubview:pdfView];

}
```

and it display the PDF without Problems.

The only thing I found is

```
UIView tmpView = (UIView)currentView;
```

you allocated tmpview statically, it should be.

```
UIView *tmpView = (UIView *)currentView;
```

Otherwise test if your data is valid Pdf.

Comment: Hi Ivion,  Thanks for your reply. I am new to Objective-C. I use WLanguage(Windev Mobile) to build iOS apps which generated Objective-C code. The language I use doesn't have support for PDF so trying to run Objective-C code from WLanguage code. I could see the PDF is correct when I debug but somewhere it is not adding it to view.

Comment: If you are using PDF functions you have to add 'PDFKit.framework' In Xcode you can add with linked Frameworks. I don't know how to add it using WLanguage.

Comment: Correct. I added that in Xcode. Didn't compile/build when it wasn't there. Probably something related to ViewController which I don't see in WLanguage.

Comment: Could You set at breakpoint in Xcode in the beginning of your code and check if tempview is perhaps nil.

Comment: This is the error I get. -[CFenPrincipaleViewController addSubview:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4884f5900 . currentView if i open in debugger show me my View. tmpView when i try to open in debugger says could not load data quick look data for tmpView

Comment: Try to change it to  [[tmpView view] addSubview:pdfView]; I think you currentView is of type UIViewcontroller not UIView.

Comment: Hi Ivion, Thanks that did work, Just need to fix few things. Like the pdf displays only partially as I am using a rectangle. My pdf has like 30-40 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good article which explains in details how to use the `PDFView`. [Tutorial](https://medium.com/mindorks/rendering-pdf-documents-using-pdfkit-9ac4944a6dfb).

Some code in Swift. I know you asked it in Objective-C but since you are into iOS, you should be able to understand the context.

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MFI_2018_01", ofType: "pdf") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            // pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I glanced through this one and changed the code accordingly but that didn't work.